# How to name custom metrics in Keras fit output

Tags: python, keras

I am using custom metrics when training my Keras model. It works fine, except that the metrics names in the output of `model.fit_generator(...)` are not interpretable (NB: Tensorboard also uses these wrong names).

Here is a reproducible example of what I am doing: the metrics are using one parameter (in addition to the prediction and ground truth), so I defined a factory to generate a parameterless metric function, similar to this:

```
def my_dummy_metric(y_true, y_pred, the_param=1.0):
    return the_param * keras.backend.ones((1))

def my_metric_factory(the_param=1.0):
    def fn(y_true, y_pred):
        return my_dummy_metric(y_true, y_pred, the_param=the_param)

    return fn

my_second_metric = my_metric_factory(2.0)
my_other_metric = my_metric_factory(3.14)
```

Then I compile and train my model:

```
model.compile(my_optim, my_loss, [my_second_metric, my_other_metric])
history = model.fit_generator(...)
print(history.params['metrics'])
```

My trouble is that the metric names in `history` are `fn`, `fn_1`, `val_fn` and `val_fn_1`. These names are also used by Tensorboard and you need to know the implem details to understand them.

On the contrary, I don't have this problem when using a simple custom function, without factory:

```
model.compile(my_optim, my_loss, [my_dummy_metric])
history = model.fit_generator(...)
print(history.params['metrics'])
```

Would it be possible to obtain `my_XXX_metric` as output names also in the factory-based use case?

**Environment:** Using Keras 2.2.4, TF 1.14.0, Python 3.7

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. In the metric factory, just set an appropriate `__name__` of metric function. For example:

```
def my_metric_factory(the_param=1.0):
    def fn(y_true, y_pred):
        return my_dummy_metric(y_true, y_pred, the_param=the_param)

    fn.__name__ = 'metricname_{}'.format(the_param)
    return fn
```

Answer (score 5):

If anyone's using TF 2.0 or later with **default metrics (not custom metrics)**, you can try name argument in metrics as follows:

```
# Recall inherits Metric class and similarly name of most of the metrics could be changed
recall = tf.keras.metrics.Recall(name = 'custom_name')
model.compile(loss=..., optimizer=...,
                        metrics=[recall])
model.fit(...)
```

If you would like to give custom name for metrics such as precision@k, recall@k, TopKCategoricalAccuracy, you could follow something like below:

```
k = 5
precision = tf.keras.metrics.Precision(top_k=k, name = 'precision_' + str(k))
model.compile(loss=..., optimizer=...,
                        metrics=[precision])
model.fit(...)
```

Source:

1. https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/metrics/Recall
2. https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/metrics